# Java, averaging a list of numbers

Tags: java, average

In the following Java code, my average temperature is 1 decimal place off.

For example Instead of being `69.0` it's `6.9`.

The input can be any 10 numbers. So lets say I input 10 temperatures and each 1 is 10 degrees.  The total for the 10 inputs is 100, so the average should be 10 but instead I'm receiving an average of 1.0.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NumberAboveAverage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int TotalTemps = 10;
        double[] numbers = new double[TotalTemps];
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        double max = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < numbers.length; n++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a temperature: ");
            numbers[n] = input.nextInt();

            if (numbers[n] > max) {
               max = numbers[n];
            }
            sum = numbers[n];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            sum = numbers[i];
        }

        average = sum / 10;    //average is not an average of the numbers.
        System.out.println("Average temp = " + average);

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] > average) {
               count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count + " days were above average");
    }
}
```

Comment: Without real data to look at nobody will be able to help you.  Please show your input data, results, and what you expected.  Also, your problem is likely due to the well-known problem of floats not being able to represent decimal numbers exactly, compounded by rounding errors.

Comment: @jaielob Its because you're not summing them together. It gets to the end and divides 10 by the total (10), instead of the sum (100) by the total. Try more cases and you will see that this is why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not actually summing the numbers together.

It should be `sum += numbers[i];`

not `sum = numbers[i];`

You also appear to be attempting to do this twice, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Man, I'm constantly amazed at the speed people answer questions here...Yeah it was an easy fix, but still, I read through the program and there were already 3 answers...

Comment: Ah I now see. Thank you. I've been coding for like 6 hrs now and my head is spinning LOL. It also doesn't help the I am a beginner to Java.

Answer (score 1):

You sum twice (second for-loop) and do it wrongly with: 
`sum = numbers[n];` 
instead of: 
`sum += numbers[n];`

You should change your code to:

```
...
         for (int n = 0; n < numbers.length; n++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a temperature: ");
            numbers[n] = input.nextInt();

            if (numbers[n] > max) {
               max = numbers[n];
            }
            sum += numbers[n];
         }

         // SECOND FOR LOOP REMOVED !!!

         average = sum / 10;
         System.out.println("Average temp = " + average);

        ...
```

Comment: nothing like spoon-feeding an answer without taking effort to explain.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you're too quick for me :) check again!

Comment: @alfasin there's really no need to post the code in its entirety. It just makes it look like you're feeding him the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `+`

```
sum = numbers[n];
```

needs to be

```
sum += numbers[n];
```

This does nothing,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    sum = numbers[i];
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
average = sum / 10;
```

with

```
average = sum / 10.0;
```

Comment: This shouldn't matter since sum is a double and holds doubles.