# Random Average Java

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to get a program that can generate some random numbers and then find the average of those random numbers, all within set parameters.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomAverage {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();

        System.out.print("Enter n: ");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        double sum =
```

And I know I need to end the program like this:

```
System.out.print("Computer generated " + n + " random numbers in range between 1 – 100 and the average " + __ + " is: ");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: you should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java , then just add them up and divide by total numbers

Comment: What you have so far isn't really anything.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441092/java-averaging-a-list-of-numbers?rq=1

Comment: Stupid question:  Do you know how to take an average?  (I mean, on paper, not in a computer program.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use random integers:

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   sum += random.nextInt();
}
double average = sum/n;
```

Otherwise check out the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) on `Random` for other means of generating random numbers i.e. within a range etc.